# Bind IsEnabled property of MenuItem from inside DataTemplate to a Window property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate, datacontext

I have a similar issue to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270074/wpf-binding-to-isenabled-property-in-listbox-contextmenus-menuitem) but since it has not been clearly answered I want to ask it again. I have a `TreeView` which is bound to an `ObservableCollection` via a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. I basically recreate a folder structure similar to a File Explorer and have a `ContextMenu` with options like Cut, Paste, etc. I want the Paste option to be enabled only when I have a cut object so I bind it to a `Property` of the `Window`.

XAML simplified:

```
<Window x:Name="mainWindow">    
    <TabControl>    
        <TabItem x:Name="tabNotes" Header="Notes">
            <TreeView x:Name="treeViewNotes" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static mvvm:DataSources.LoadedFolders}}" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow}">
                <TreeView.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Paste" Click="TabNotesPaste" IsEnabled="{Binding NoteTabPasteEnabled}"/>                          
                    </ContextMenu>
                </TreeView.ContextMenu>                                
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type dataclasses:NoteFolder}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Paste" Click="TabNotesPaste" IsEnabled="{Binding NoteTabPasteEnabled}"/>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Title}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.Resources>
            </TreeView>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

The Window implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _noteTabFolderPasteEnabled = false;
    public bool NoteTabPasteEnabled { get { return _noteTabFolderPasteEnabled; } set { _noteTabFolderPasteEnabled = value; OnMyPropertyChanged(() => NoteTabPasteEnabled); } }

    //...
}
```

For the `ContextMenu` of the `TreeView` it works fine, but for the `ContextMenu` of the `DataTemplate` it does not. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Refer my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104193/how-to-bind-command-into-contextmenu-in-datatemplate/30105635#30105635

Comment: I am already using the Tag. Can it be done another way?

Comment: Since ContextMenu is not part of VisualTree it is not possible in any direct ways.Another method to use BindingProxy to achieve the same. http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Comment: Or use `PlacementTarget`, which would be in the other visual tree, not the context menu's visual tree.